# Can I have the output as a directory with input having wildcards in Snakemake? To get around jobs that fail and force rule order

Tags: snakemake

I have a rule that runs a tool on multiple samples (some fail), I use -k option to proceed with remaining samples. However, for my next step I need to check the output of the first rule and create a single text summary file. I can not get the next rule to execute after the first rule.

I have tried various things, including rule fastQC_post having the output with wildcards. But then if I use this as input for the next rule I can't have one output file. If I use expand in the input of rule checkQC with the {sample} as the list of all samples determined at initiation this breaks as not all samples successfully reached the fastQC stage.

I really just want to be able to create the post_fastqc_reports folder in the fastQC_post rule and use this as input for my checkQC rule. OR be able to force it to run checkQC after fastQC_post has finished, but again checkpoints doesn't work as some of the jobs for fastQC_post fail.

I would like something like below: (this does not work as the output directory does not use the wildcard)

Surely there is an easier way to force rule order?

```
rule fastQC_post:
    """
    runs FastQC on the trimmed reads
    """
    input:
        projectDir+batch+"_trimmed_reads/{sample}_trimmed.fq.gz"
    output: directory(projectDir+batch+"post_fastqc_reports/")
    log:
        projectDir+"logs/{sample}_trimmed_fastqc.log"
    params:
        p = fastqcParams,
    shell:
        """
    /home/apps/pipelines/FastQC/CURRENT {params.p} -o {output} {input}
        """



rule checkQC:
    input: rules.parse_sampleFile.output[0],rules.parse_sampleFile.output[1], rules.parse_sampleFile.output[2], directory(projectDir+batch+"post_fastqc_reports/")

    output:
        projectDir+"summaries/"+batch+"_summary_tg.txt"
        , projectDir+"summaries/"+batch+"_listForFastqc.txt"
        , projectDir+"summaries/"+batch+"_trimmingResults.txt"
        , projectDir+"summaries/"+batch+"_summary_fq.txt"
    log:
        projectDir+"logs/"+stamp+"_checkQC.log"
    shell:
        """
        python python_scripts/fastqc_checks.py --input_file {log} --output {output[1]} {batchCmd}
        python python_scripts/trimGalore_checks.py --list_file {input[0]} --single {input[1]} --pair {input[2]} --log {log} --output {output[0]} --trimDir {trimDir} --sampleFile \
{input[3]} {batchCmd}
        """
```

With the above I get the error that not all output and log contain same wildcard as input for the fastqc_post rule.

I just want to be able to run my checkQC rule after my fastqc_post rule (regardless of failures of jobs in the fastqc_post rule)